# Laravel 4.2 site doesn't work on localhost

Tags: laravel-4.2

I just downloaded a site based on laravel 4.2 and it isn't working on localhost. When i try go to /public chrome show "no connection" or something like that. I checked logs - nothing. I tried add some permissions to storage but only in windows (Properties > Sharing and there).

Comment: No no. When i go localhost/myapp I see public folder but when i go in chrome shows information about no connection. I made chmod on storage. Still same.

I see when I change main function return to just 'test' it shows normally.

Comment: I removed the flag and the comment.